# Issues with masking in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-masking

We have set a normal masking policy on few columns based on role. If my role can view the data, those columns data will be visible otherwise data is masked for all other roles. It was working fine until we introduced tag based masking.

we created tag based masking and applied on those columns with out unsetting old policy, so we dropped everything(both old and new) and created masking from scratch.

Now the issue is latest data(loaded through job) is masked properly and old data is masked even though that role should have access to the data.

In that table we have multiple sources of data, only few sources have this issue and for others data is unmasked(both old and new data) and it is proper.

When i see the policy reference i can see only new tag based masking policy applied on those columns.

what can be possible reasons for this kind of issue??

Comment: Are you saying that data in the same column is masked differently depending on when it was loaded or where it was sourced from? If not, please could you clarify your question- maybe illustrate it with examples?

Comment: Maybe also update your question with the masking policy definition, the tag definition and the relevant table/column definitions